# Change CKEditor Keystrokes at runtime

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to change the Keystrokes config of CKEditor at runtime.

My goal: <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> should submit the form.

Unfortunately I can't configure CKEditor via js-configuration, since I use django-ckeditor (related issue [#322](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/322))

I tried this:

```
$(function() {
    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
        for(x in CKEDITOR.instances){
            var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[x];
            instance.config.Keystrokes.push([ CTRL + 13 /* Enter */, 'Save' ]);
        };
    })
})
```

... but I get:

> TypeError: instance.config.Keystrokes is undefined

How can I modify the configuration of CKEditor to make ctrl+enter submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CKEDITOR.editor.setKeystroke](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke) like this (note the small 's' in 'save'):

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.setKeystroke(CKEDITOR.CTRL + 13, 'save');
})
```

Comment: Yes, this works, Thank you. And there is an interesting follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740695/ckeditor-save-is-different-than-submit