# CKEditor 'save' is different than submit

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, jquery-events

I use this, to submit the form if you hit ctrl+enter:

```
$(function() {
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
        evt.editor.setKeystroke(CKEDITOR.CTRL + 13, 'save');
    })
})
```

Unfortunately this seems to be a bit different to pressing the submit button.

If I hit ctrl+enter I get a popup with a warning that there is changed data in the form, and that this data would get lost. If I choose "leave the page", then everything works fine (not data gets lost).

How can I make ctrl+enter work like pressing the submit button?

Comment: Do you have a separate submit button or does your form have only ckeditor field? I can try and give you some instructions to find out the exact event handler that is registered on your page, making it displaying the popup message. Do you have installed Firefox or Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event is triggered when you save the form.

Try this to override the save event and remove the event handler:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('save', function(evt) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;

        // if the above line doesn't work,
        // replace it with the next line removing the two slashes
        // $(window).off('beforeunload');
    });
}
```

Comment: This works: `window.onbeforeunload = null;`. This helped me a lot. I started an extra bounty to reward your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing "save" with "submit".

CKEditor has a cache which saves the things you've typed so when you loose connection, etc. your content won't be gone.

Comment: I replaced "save" with "submit", but now nothing happens. Are there any docs about the list of allowed values?